# Is a transit visa needed for Kuwait?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, transit-visas, kuwait

I am travelling from Delhi to New York. I will be transiting via Kuwait, with a stopover of 1 hour 40 minute. Do I need any transit visa for Kuwait?

I have an Indian passport. I will not leave the airport.

Comment: What's your passport? How long are you staying for? Do you plan on leaving the terminal (don't think so but still worth asking)?

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nope** - no transit visa required for a 1h40 transit in Kuwait en route to the USA as an Indian citizen.

> / 07APR16 / 1828 UTC
>
> National India (IN)             Transit Kuwait (KW) Destination USA (US)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>
> - In case of transit connections beyond 8 hours, passengers must remain airside and be accommodated in the airport
>     transit hotel.

Source: [Timaticweb](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&TR=KWI&DE=JFK&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)